# Generalization of Bolzano theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory

Is there a generalization to Bolzano theorem when $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: The continuous image of a connected set is connected.

Comment: This site is for questions at research level. For general questions in mathematics see [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be various generalizations. My favorite one is this.

Let $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ be continuous functions on the unit cube.
And suppose that each of them takes values of opposite sign on the opposite facets
(each on its own pair of the opposite facets). Then all $f_j$ have a common
zero inside the cube.

Comment: Is this Poincare Miranda theorem?

Comment: Are there other generalizations? thank you

Comment: I am not sure about the name. It follows from the Brouwer theorem, see, for example Hurewicz and Wallman, Dimension theory, Ch. IV, 1D.

Comment: Of course there are other generalizations. One of them stated in a comment to your question:-)

Comment: Yes, Wikipedia says that this is called Poincare-Miranda theorem.